# How to find out where (in which .js file) a knockout observable is being created initially?

Tags: debugging, knockout.js

The following `.html` snippet retrieves the value of a ko observable named `title`:

```
<th data-bind="text: title"></th>
```

Only knowing the `.html` file, is there a way to systematically find out (backtrace?), where - in which `.js` file of the project - this specific `title` observable is being created initially?

If so, how can this be achieved?

Knockout 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can run the project, you could try the following steps (example uses Chrome browser):

1. Find the dom element bound to the observable:

   - right click on element -> Inspect
   - in elements tab, right click element -> Copy -> copy selector
2. Find some knockout context for this element to spot the viewmodel containing the observable

   - in console: `ko.contextFor(document.querySelector('<paste element selector>'))`
   - browse `$data` (currently bound viewmodel) or any of the `$parents` (in case of foreach-es...) to find the viemodel name containing the observable
   - copy the name of the viewmodel
3. Find the javascript file containing the viewmodel:

   - in dev-tools hit CTRL-SHIFT-F
   - paste viemodel name

In the results window, you'll find all files containing this viewmodel name (and the declaration of the observable).